# Get the value in multidimensional arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to get values of multidimensional array.

Array is as shown below

```
        Array
          (
               [id] => 1448639278717703
               [birthday] => 06/23/1993
               [education] => Array
                     (
                           [0] => stdClass Object
                              (
                                [school] => stdClass Object
                                     (
                                       [id] => 291422000916149
                                       [name] => Vijeta High School
                                      )

                                 [type] => High School
                              )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                               (
                                  [school] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                       [id] => 133445980012001
                                       [name] => Vijnana Vihara Residential School
                                     )

                                   [type] => High School
                               )

                           [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                   [concentration] => Array
                                     (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => 111995945484851
                                                [name] => Electronics 
                                             )

                                       )

                                     [school] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                         [id] => 104121832956302
                                         [name] => Vignan University
                                        )

                                     [type] => College
                               )

                        )
                )
```

Let take the array as $graphObject then I tried like shown below

```
        $graphObject['education'][0]['school']['name']
```

But this doesn't worked.

I want to get

1. School name and type of it.
2. Concentration name and its school name

Example:
I have to get like
  High school:  Vijeta High School
  High school:  Vijnana Vihara Residential School
  Concentration in Electronics at Vignan University

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to convert everything into array -

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($array),1);
```

Where $array is your array.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$graphObject['education'][0]->school->name;
```

Comment: Actually it is $graphObject['education'][0]->school->name

Answer (score 0):

Your innter array contain an object your acces that value like array.

If you want to solve this issue convert your inner ojbect into array and then access the same that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your array is an object array,

convert it before with this function:

```
function objectToArray( $object )
{
    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
    {
        return $object;
    }
    if( is_object( $object ) )
    {
        $object = get_object_vars( $object );
    }
    return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}
```

then:

```
$graphObject =  objectToArray($graphObject);

print_r ($graphObject['education'][0]['school']['name']);
```